# B2 Visa for my Employee/Partner

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

My girlfriend has been working for my company in the US since 2019, with a modest salary. We are trying to figure out the best way for her to visit my family in the US and I have written an invitation letter and an employment verification letter, both with my name on them. Is it alright for my name to be on both documents, or should our Human Resources director sign the employment verification letter?

Additionally, as she is a full-time contractor, would she be allowed to work for the US company during her visit, or should she take the whole duration of her trip off?

Comment: For B2 visa you do not need any documentation, not needed and nobody will look for them. Follow the instruction for visa.

Comment: For B2, we will need to provide verification from the employer about her work status and salary (I'm her boss) and also an invitation letter with the friend or family you're staying with is optional but highly recommended.

Comment: Where are you (since you're inviting her) and where is she?  What is her citizenship/residency?

Comment: What ties does she have to her country of residence? For how long is she planning to visit?

Comment: "is she allowed to work for this US company during her visit": no.

Comment: I am a US citizen, we are both abroad right now in Indonesia living together until she can come to the US. She is from Vietnam, we both came here in January.

She's planning on visiting for 1-2 months. She mostly has strong financial accounts there and family, in terms of ties nothing concrete like a property or business

Comment: You say "full-time contractor" do you mean that or is she actually an employee

Comment: @mmmmmm She's worked full time (40hr week) since 2019, but given shes an employee based overseas shes not Full Time (W2) per see, but a full time contractor